# Issue when manipulate a collection of input file pattern for a ZIP task

Tags: gradle, groovy

We build libraries for various targets with one build configuration with Gradle (version 6.9). Our Gradle environment use a special plugin to provide all tasks with the same configuration file syntax for all projects. This plugin still contains a fix implementation for putting target specific artifacts into archives - one archive for each target. This implementation works fine but should change to using a generic configuration.

```
tasks.create(zipTaskName, Zip) {
    archiveName "${artifactName}_${targetId}.zip"
    into("${artifactName}/${targetId}") {
        from "${artifactDir}"
        // TODO: use pattern fron config file
        include "*_${targetId}.zip.checksum"
        include "*_${targetId}.lib"
    }
    into("${artifactName}/inc") {
        from "${includeDir}"
    }
}
```

But my new Groovy implementation doesn't generate archives anymore.

The new implementation have to manipulate the pattern for each enty of collection to put the target in front of the first dot in pattern - it isn't much complicated (example with hard coded collection):

```
tasks.create(zipTaskName, Zip) {
    archiveName "${artifactName}_${targetId}.zip"
    into("${artifactName}/${targetId}") {
        from "${artifactDir}"
        // collection in line below will changed by a configuration variable
        ['*_${targetId}.lib', '*_${targetId}.zip.checksum'].each { includeArtifact ->
            include "${includeArtifact.replace('.', '_${targetId}.')}"
        }
    }
    into("${artifactName}/inc") {
        from "${includeDir}"
    }
}
```

But this implementation does no more generate any archive. The log output says '`NO-SOURCE`':

```
...
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.Node] Checking if all dependencies are complete for :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.Node] All dependencies are complete for :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskNode] Checking if all must successors are complete for :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskNode] Checking if all finalizing successors are complete for :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskNode] All task dependencies are complete for :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker for ':': released lock on :
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1.33 completed (1 worker(s) in use)
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker for ':': released lock on root.1.33
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker for ':': acquired lock on :
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1.33 started (1 worker(s) in use).
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker for ':': acquired lock on root.1.33
[INFO] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor] :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7 (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Task :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7' started
[LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] 
[LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7 NO-SOURCE
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter] Putting task artifact state for task ':zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7' into context took 0.0 secs.
[INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree] file or directory 'C:\Users\00024162\Projekte\LegacyLib\legacyStm32Lib_master\doc\generator', not found
[INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultEmptySourceTaskSkipper] Skipping task ':zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter] Removed task artifact state for task ':zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7' from context.
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Task :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7'
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Task :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7' completed
[INFO] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor] :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7 (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan] Node :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7 finished executing
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan] Node :zipGCC_ARM_5_4M7 completed, executed: true
...
```

Why there are no sources for zip task, there should at leased soures all files from line '`from "${includeDir}"`'?

Does anybody can help me for this issue. I still have less experiance with Groovy.

**Edit:**

I have solved the issue using following snippet:

```
tasks.create(zipTaskName, Zip) {
    archiveName "${artifactName}_${targetId}.zip"
    into("${artifactName}/${targetId}") {
        from "${artifactDir}"
        // collection in line below will changed by a configuration variable
        ['*_${targetId}.lib', '*_${targetId}.zip.checksum'].each { includeArtifact ->
            def artifactPattern = includeArtifact.replace(".", "_${targetId}.")
            include "${artifactPattern}"
        }
    }
    into("${artifactName}/inc") {
        from "${includeDir}"
        include "**/*"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a working minimal example of both the working and not working tasks? There's to much to guess here, or too much to invent to get your code working for us

Comment: I will try to put a minimal examle together